Does $\mathbf R\text{Hom}_R(k, -)\otimes_R^{\mathbf L} k$ commute with co-products?
Let $(R, \mathfrak m, k)$ be a commutative Noetherian local ring. Then, is it true that $\mathbf R\text{Hom}_R(k, -)\otimes_R^{\mathbf L} k$ commutes with arbitrary co-products?

$\newcommand{\RHom}{\mathbf{R}\mathrm{Hom}_R} \newcommand{\Lotimes}{\otimes^\mathbf{L}_R} \newcommand{\fib}{\mathrm{fib}}$
I claim that this happens if and only if the same is true for $\RHom(k,-)$, if and only if $k$ is perfect as an $R$-module, if and only if $R$ is regular. What I prove below is that the assumption guarantees that $k$ is dualizable over $R$.
For this, note that $k\Lotimes \RHom(k,R)$ and $\RHom(k,k)$ are both (derived) $m$-complete (derived) $R$-modules, for example because they are both (derived) $k$-modules. Thus, the canonical map $k\Lotimes \RHom(k,R)\to \RHom(k,k)$ is an equivalence if and only if it is one after (derived) tensoring with $k$ (very elementarily, using the observation that they are $k$-modules and that the canonical map is $k$-linear: a $k$-module $M$ is a natural retract, in $R$-modules, of $k\Lotimes M$).
But after (derived) tensoring with $k$, this follows from the assumption: the map $X\Lotimes \RHom(k,R)\Lotimes k\to \RHom(k,X)\Lotimes k$ is an equivalence for $X=R$ and both sides commutes with arbitrary homotopy colimits, hence it is an equivalence at any $X$, in particular $X=k$.
Thus the canonical map $k\Lotimes\RHom(k,R)\to \RHom(k,k)$ is an equivalence,and so $k$ is dualizable. This is known to imply that it is perfect over $R$, and thus $R$ is regular.
The converse is of course clear because it implies the result without tensoring with $k$.

The functor $\mathbf R\text{Hom}_R(k, -)$ commutes with arbitrary direct sums if and only if $k$ is a compact object in $D(R)$, that is, $k$ is perfect. Since $R$ is noetherian, $k = R/\mathfrak m$ is perfect if and only if $k$ has finite projective dimension, which by Serre occurs if and only if $R$ is regular.
Tensor products always commute with infinite direct sums.
Edit: Thus, if $R$ is regular Noetherian, then the composite functor commutes with direct sums. I do not claim the converse; I wonder if readers can improve my argument.

I am confused ... are you trying to say that if $\mathbf R \text{Hom}_R(k,-)\otimes_R^{\mathbf L}k$ commutes with arbitrary co-products, then $\mathbf R \text{Hom}_R(k,-)$  also commutes with arbitrary co-products? That is not at all clear to me ...

@uno see my edit

If the ring is regular, then every object in the bounded derived category would preserve co-products... nothing special about the residue field...I guess I should have mentioned that
